# How to add different classes to 4 column according to position of td with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
<img src="images/kategoriimg1.jpg" />
<p>Forskerspiren</p>
        </td>
         <td>
<img src="images/kategoriimg2.jpg" />
<p>Mangfold i naturen</p>
        </td>
         <td>
<img src="images/kategoriimg3.jpg" />
<p>Kropp og helse</p>
        </td>
         <td>
<img src="images/kategoriimg4.jpg" />
<p>Verdensrommet</p>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
<img src="images/kategoriimg5.jpg" />
<p>Fenomener og
stoffer</p>
        </td>
         <td>
<img src="images/kategoriimg6.jpg" />
 <p>bla</p>
        </td>
         <td>
<img src="images/kategoriimg7.jpg" /> 
  <p>bla</p>
        </td>
         <td>
<img src="images/kategoriimg8.jpg" /> 
 <p>bla</p>
        </td>

    </tr>
  .....
  .....
   // more tr and td with images like above
  .... 


</table>
```

Now I want to add class grid_3, alpha first to all first tds, grid_3 middle to all second and third tds and middle and grid_3 omega last to all forth tds with jquery like this.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="grid_3 alpha first">
<img src="images/kategoriimg1.jpg" />
<p>Forskerspiren</p>
        </td>
         <td class="grid_3 middle">
<img src="images/kategoriimg2.jpg" />
<p>Mangfold i naturen</p>
        </td>
         <td class="grid_3 middle">
<img src="images/kategoriimg3.jpg" />
<p>Kropp og helse</p>
        </td>
         <td class="grid_3 omega last">
<img src="images/kategoriimg4.jpg" />
<p>Verdensrommet</p>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="grid_3 alpha first">
<img src="images/kategoriimg5.jpg" />
<p>Forskerspiren</p>
        </td>
         <td class="grid_3 middle">
<img src="images/kategoriimg6.jpg" />
<p>Mangfold i naturen</p>
        </td>
         <td class="grid_3 middle">
<img src="images/kategoriimg7.jpg" />
<p>Kropp og helse</p>
        </td>
         <td class="grid_3 omega last">
<img src="images/kategoriimg8.jpg" />
<p>Verdensrommet</p>
        </td>

    </tr>
   ....
   ....



</table>
```

Comment: As you can see by the answers, there's about a zillion ways to do it.  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $td = $('td').addClass('grid_3');
    $td.filter(':not(:first-child,:last-child)').addClass('middle');
    $td.filter(':first-child').addClass('first alpha');
    $td.filter(':last-child').addClass('last omega');
```

Comment: Using `removeClass` right after `addClass` in an effort to target certain elements is an example of how to under-utilize your framework.

Comment: @Stephen - I agree. I changed my answer.

Comment: Much better, +1  Now you just have to lose the Hungarian notation and you've got a sweet piece of jQuery on your hands.

Comment: Caching the `td` elements as you have done--and using `filter`--is much more efficient than @Ryan's method.

Comment: Hungarian... the `$td`? I thought hungarian would be something like `eTd`.

Comment: Trying not to *over-critique*, but I cannot resist:  you should change `$('table tr td')` to `$('td')`.  In your current form, Sizzle will get all `td` elements, then check if they are children of `tr`, then check if the `tr` are children of `table`.  Since these things can be inferred, `$('td')` will be faster.

Comment: @Josiah:  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1778-Using-Variable-In-jQuery-Code-Is-Just-Hungarian-Notation.htm

Comment: @Stephen RE Link: I am not a fan of Hungarian notation, however I do find it useful to distinguish between jquery objects and DOM objects. One of the most common jQuery errors I see is `$(this).value` vs `$(this).val()` because the types are so closely related I generally use the $ to indicate a cached jquery local variable.

Comment: @Stephen - hmm I feel I owe you a few points! ;) well thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
$("table tr").each(function(){
  $(this).find("td:eq(0)").attr("class","grid_3 alpha first");
  $(this).find("td:eq(1),td:eq(2)").attr("class","grid_3 middle");
  $(this).find("td:eq(3)").attr("class","grid_3 omega last");
});
```

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect.  Those square brackets should be parens.

Comment: +1 I like this. Just to add you could use slice to isolate the two TDs instead of the comma-separated selectors: `$(this).find("td").slice(1, 2).attr("class","grid_3 middle");`

Comment: Changing this to use the jQuery `eq()` method instead of the `eq` css selector will improve performance.  http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 0):

Don't even use jQuery :). Use the CSS3 nth-child selectors:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: And what if the table is being created or a style is being added dynamically?

Comment: Or your user's browser doesn't support CSS3?

Comment: @treeface - that wasn't specified. I'm assuming its the same format always.

@ender - he's asking for jQuery, which, also uses the CSS3 selectors by default, so either way he's using CSS3

Comment: indeed CSS3 selectors are used in jQuery, but he did specify that he wanted to do it "in jQuery". Regardless, your link is a good contribution to this discussion, so thanks!

Comment: thanks. but the overcomplicated jQuery will be used. using more memory on the browser and such. but who cares - it looks pretty :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table tr td').addClass('grid_3');
$('table tr td:nth-child(0)').addClass('alpha first');
$('table tr td:nth-child(1)').addClass('middle');
$('table tr td:nth-child(2)').addClass('middle');
$('table tr td:nth-child(3)').addClass('omega last');
```